# How to add the value in input file as a column in exported output file in powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I have a input file(input.txt) with the following data. The below data are saved in my domain as contacts. My task is to identify the corresponding mail id in my domain for these contacts.

```
 abcd@otherdomain.com
 efgh@otherdomain.com
 ijkl@otherdomain.com
```

Below is the powershell script I wrote to accomplish the task. The targetaddress of these contacts will be my domain email id. But the problem here is, while exporting I need the input data also to be appended to my result.

```
Write-Host "Reading Input File.. "
$users=""
ForEach ($contact in $(Get-Content 'Input.txt')) 
{
    $DomainId = Get-ADObject -Filter  {(mail -eq $contact) -and (ObjectClass -eq "Contact")} -Properties * | Select targetAddress
    $DomainId = $DomainId.targetAddress.remove(0,5) 
    $users+= (Get-AdUser -Filter {Mail -eq $DomainId} -Properties * | Select Mail)      
}
Write-Host "Exporting to CSV.."   
$users | Export-CSV -Path 'output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Below is the current output (output.csv)

```
Mail;
ab@mydomain.com;
ef@mydomain.com;
ij@mydomain.com;
```

But the expected output is,

```
Mail;InputId;
ab@mydomain.com;abcd@otherdomain.com;
ef@mydomain.com;efgh@otherdomain.com;
ij@mydomain.com;ijkl@otherdomain.com;
```

Is there a possibility to get the expected output. If so, please assist. Many thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but something like this could work:

```
Write-Host "Reading Input File.. "
$users = foreach ($contact in (Get-Content 'Input.txt')) 
{
    $DomainId = Get-ADObject -Filter {
                        (mail -eq $contact) -and (ObjectClass -eq "Contact")
                    } -Properties * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty targetAddress

    $DomainId = $DomainId.Remove(0,5)
    $Mail = (Get-AdUser -Filter {Mail -eq $DomainId} -Properties Mail).Mail

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        InputId = $DomainId
        Mail = $Mail
    } 
}

Write-Host "Exporting to CSV.."   
$users | Export-CSV -Path 'output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

You want PSCustomObjects going into Export-CSV, with one property per column. And they are easy to build by casting from a hashtable, instead of using a lot of Add-Member.